# Создать иерархию типов – файл для чтения, файл для записи и файл для чтения и записи

Tags: c++, ооп

У меня есть 4 задачки,первые 3 я сделал,осталась только эта:

**Создать иерархию типов – файл для чтения, файл для записи и файл для чтения и записи. Классы должны иметь конструкторы, включая конструктор копирования, виртуальные деструкторы, перегруженные функции вывода в поток и ввод из потока.**

Не могу понять какой вид должна иметь эта иерархия и какая структура программы.Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Похоже на аналог потоков iostream

Comment: Конструкторы могут получать файловый поток, копировать из буфера другого потока, деструкторы _закрывают поток. Не думаю, что есть нужда написать собственный класс файлового потока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже эта задача больше на развитие креативного мышления. :) Ну и на закрепление материала по наследованию.
Ну один из вариантов (классический пример на наследование):
[image: классическая иерархия]

Здесь делаете `class myfile` полностью виртуальным, т.е. его объекты нельзя создавать. В нем держите дескриптор потока или указатель на файл, если будете работать с файловыми функциями, а не потоками. В `class imyfile` определяете только оператор ввода `operator>>` - это будет файл только для чтения. В `class omyfile` определяете только оператор вывода`operator<<` - это будет файл только для записи. Ну и от них наследуется `class iomyfile` - который от предков получит и ввод и вывод в файл.

Другой вариант - когда есть `class iomyfile` и от него наследуют `imyfile` и `omyfile`.
[image: иерархия 2]
Базовый класс может всё, а наследники - какое-то подмножество его функционала. Так вы ограничиваете функционал базового класса - по сути создаете интерфейсы.
В любом случае это больше демонстрационные примеры.